# C# Custom allocator presenter with a VMR9

Tags: c#, directshow, direct3d, directshow.net

I'm trying to get a custom allocator-presenter working with C#.

Firstly, I create a Direct3DEx object on the main thread and create a device. I next create a custom allocator-presenter object.  This then creates surfaces using the device I created earlier.

I run the graph but, naturally, a bit later I then call the Stop call on the direct show graph.  At this point the stop function causes a frame to be presented.  This presentation occurs on a different thread.  At this point the Direct3D object is then used and I instantly have a problem.  The Direct3D object is marshalled for the main thread which is currently blocked handling the Stop function.

So how can I get round this?

Should the PresentImage call perform a BeginInvoke to handle the frame later on?  Or is there some way I can encourage the Direct3D object to be created such that it can be called from any thread?